# Where to keep git submodules inside of a go project?

Tags: git, go, git-submodules

I want to add a submodule to my go project.

The submodule will contain some `.proto` files and some go files. I will use protos to generate grpc-gateway files using my Makefile, which will have the same package as the go files in the repo. The repo which contains these protos is not mine, and others are developing it. I won't commit these gateway files generated.

Is there any specific structure for such files in golang projects? Should I keep them in pkg directory?

I have three folders of build, configs, templates currently in my project.

Comment: There is no standard way to handle git submodules within Go. From Go's perspective, git submodules don't exist. They're just part of the directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep them in the `pkg` directory,  maybe at `pkg/proto`.

The package names for the generated go files will be present in the `go_package` attribute in the `.proto` file. For example,

```proto
option go_package = "external/api/messages";
```

Then after compilation, the package name inside the go file would be

```golang
package messages
```

This is the folder structure

```sh
$ tree
.
`-- pkg
    `-- proto
        `-- messages
            |-- messages.pb.go
            `-- messages.proto
```

In order to import it, you'll have to update your `go.mod` file

```
replace external/api v0.0.0 => ./pkg/proto
```

afterwards, you can import it using

```
import (
    "external/api/messages"
)
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to keep your project dependencies inside your project then you better keep them inside a `vendor` directory.

But usually I use go modules for that.

Also might be useful for you:
https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout